# MySQL joins between two tables and calculate 3 numbers in percent

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with my MySQL statement and I'm not getting any further cause I need some backup and I hope you'll take your time to check my problem out

This picture shows what I would like to achive.

[expected results, screenshot from another site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDA01.png)
cc

```
  global $wpdb; 
  $table_registreringer = $wpdb->prefix . 'registreringer'; 
  $table_redskaber = $wpdb->prefix . 'redskaber';

CREATE TABLE $table_registreringer 
    (
        reg_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        reg_redskabs_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY  (reg_id),
        FOREIGN KEY  (reg_redskabs_id) REFERENCES $table_redskaber(redskabs_id)     
 )
CREATE TABLE $table_redskaber 
    (
        redskabs_id INT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
        redskabs_navn CHAR (20),
        PRIMARY KEY  (redskabs_id)
    )
```

```html
<p> wp_registreringer Table dummy </p>
<table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
  <tr align="left" valign="top">
    <td><strong>reg_id</strong></td>
    <td><strong>redskabs_id</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td> 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
</table>


  <p>wp_redskaber Table dummy</p>

  <table align="left" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%">
    <tr align="left" valign="top">
      <td><strong>redskabs_id</strong></td>
      <td><strong>redskabs_navn</strong></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Flue</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Orm</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Spin</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

This doesn't give me the right answer. but I would like it to make calcucalte the SUM of how many times the "redskabs_navn" has been chosen. and devide it with every registration made.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS redskaber, COUNT(*) / T.total * 100 AS percent  
FROM wp_redskaber as r,
(SELECT COUNT(*) AS total FROM wp_redskaber JOIN wp_registreringer ON 
reg_redskabs_id=redskabs_id) AS T
```

[Query results now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkYW5.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this will do the trick

```
SELECT redskabs_navn , 
        ((COUNT(table_registreringer.reg_id)/ (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_registreringer))*100 ) AS percent
 FROM redskaber 
        LEFT JOIN table_registreringer
 ON redskaber.redskabs_id = table_registreringer.reg_redskabs_id
 GROUP BY redskaber.redskabs_id
```

- it is better to add an UNIQUE Constraint to `redskabs_navn` in `redskaber` table

Comment: Cool I'm pleased for your time, but will you take the time to explain to me why you did as you did cause I cant get my head around it how this works

Comment: @Mg10 If you would like to post another question, cause the code won't be clear in the comments

Comment: I could do that, but you could of course edit your answer ? :)